# how can i get a route like username.mywebsite.com or dashboard in node express

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

How can we achieve url like when we click to see user profile or dashboard in medium.com then each user looks like "https://username.medium.com". I don't know the exact name but might be called cors

Answer (score 0):

You probably want something like http://expressjs.com/en/resources/middleware/vhost.html.

But frankly, I would use something higher – nginx or Apache, depends on what you're using at the moment.

Comment: Thank you so much..Actually i want to build a website for blogging where user can write post etc their post..What should i use in your opinion as you said you would use nginx or Apache. How can i use them?